# how to mock this.route.queryParams.subscribe

Tags: karma-jasmine

i have one application where i am getting subscribe undefined error.this.route.queryParams.subscribe

i tried with multiple approaches but nothing worked.

this.route.queryParams.subscribe

Please help to mock this object

Comment: share the code and your `spec` file please

Answer (score 0):

Try using: `providers: [{ provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: { queryParams: of({ id: 1 }) } }]`

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [], // ... your imports
      declarations: [], // ...your declaration 
      providers: [{ 
           provide: ActivatedRoute, 
           useValue: { queryParams: of({ id: 1 }) } 
        }],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

make sure to replace `{ id: 1 }` with your expected route value and `import`  `of` from RxJs